# How to Flutter test TextThemes

Tags: flutter, testing, widget-test-flutter

I need to test the following piece of code to basically check if `trailingIconButton == null` then a certain text theme should be applied.

```
Text(
                    type == TileType.org
                        ? orgInfo!.name!
                        : type == TileType.user
                            ? '${userInfo!.firstName!} ${userInfo!.lastName!}'
                            : option!.title,
                    style: type == TileType.org
                        ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5
                        : type == TileType.user
                            ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6
                            : option!.trailingIconButton == null
                                ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2
                                : Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .headline5!
                                    .copyWith(fontSize: 18),
                    key: const Key('trailingIconButton'),
                  ),
```

what I wrote

```
testWidgets('Creating Custom List (giving custom options)', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(createCustomListTileUser(
          option: Options(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              title: 'henlo',
              subtitle: 'yesh',
              trailingIconButton: null)));
      final Text text =
          tester.firstWidget(find.byKey(const Key('trailingIconButton')));
      //equals bodyText2
      expect(text.style!.getTextStyle(),
          equals(Theme.of(MockBuildContext()).textTheme.bodyText2));
    });
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing now?

Comment: @Amir_P the code throws different textstyles even after passing the right kind of data

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using different contexts to get theme which results in different themes. In your application you probably have defined a `Theme` which is returned when you're using `Theme.of(context)` but that's not the case in your tests. When you're doing `Theme.of(MockBuildContext())` You're getting different one.

So to solve this you need to wrap your widgets with a theme provider with the same theme used in your application. Then use this code to compare themes:

```
expect(
    text.style!.getTextStyle(),
    equals(Theme.of(
            tester.element(find.byKey(const Key('trailingIconButton'))))
        .textTheme
        .bodyText2));
```